# How to offer food in Islam in the Sunni branch?

Tags: sunni, food

I have never seen a Muslim food offering at an altar. Can someone explain how it is done in the Sunni branch?

Comment: do you mean Allah (GOD) or his prophet Muhammad (saw)?

Comment: @Maalik His prophet Muhammad.

Comment: Allah is God. The [Quran](https://quran.com/) is the speech of Allah, further hadith also contain His quotes and teachings. Muhammad ﷺ is the Messenger of Allah - he did not write anything himself however he did have scribes write down some documents. Further what he said and did was persevered and passed on by his contemporaries and is recorded in collections of hadith. There are *several* hadith books, you can find some lists online such as on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_hadith_books) but frankly list questions are not useful and are discouraged on this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no food offerings, nor altars in Islam.

The closest thing are perhaps sacrifices. These are ritual slaughtering of animals, whose meat can then be eaten by the person himself and distributed among relatives, friends, neighbors and the poor. Certain sacrifices require that the meat to only be distributed among the poor. Ritual sacrifices in Islam include udhiyyah, aqeeqah, hadiy etc.

Another somewhat related practice could be where food is given as charity to the poor. This may be either as supererogatory act, or as part of an obligation like zakat al-fitr or kaffarah etc.

In any case there is no ritual in Islam where food is offered to Allah on an altar. The Quran rather negates such an act:

> لن ينال الله لحومها ولا دماؤها ولكن يناله التقوى منكم
>
> Their meat will not reach Allah, nor will their blood, but what reaches Him is piety from you.
>
> <sup>— [Quran 22:37](https://quran.com/22/37?translations=20)</sup>